# STOMP Spring Boot clientside ReferenceError: SockJS is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, stomp, sockjs

I want to create a simple chatapplication with STOMP Spring boot and a client, which runs later on an other domain. I created several classes and function but I can't find the solution of this error. It would be great if you could take a look at this :)

So I have two Spring Boot classes:

My WebSocketConfig looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{
    
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();

    }

    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/", "/queue/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class StompController {
    
    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public ChatMessage send(ChatMessage message) throws Exception {  
        return message;
    }
```

My Spring Boot dependencies regarding this topic:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Finally, my client connect function looks like this (vanilla JS):

```
  function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/chat");
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
          setConnected(true);
          console.log("Connected: " + frame);
          stompClient.subscribe(
            "/chat/topic/messages",
            function (messageOutput) {
              showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
            }
          );
        });
      }
```

Somehow I always receive the error: ReferenceError: SockJS is not defined

[image]

Do you may the solution of this problem without jQuery?

Comment: How are you including the SockJS client in your JavaScript application?

Comment: Hey Justin
Like this: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>